# Set Data unmapped field not work

Tags: symfony

First of all, with reference to possible duplication, I have to say that it is not the same thing because he's trying to access it and I'm trying to assign the value. And I saw that before and it didn't help me.

I'm trying to set the entity field data before I show the form, and I've tried several modes and none have worked for me and I really don't understand it.
I'm working on Symfony 4

This is the field of the form with the option `"mapped" => false`

```
->add('roleGroup', EntityType::class, array(
             'label' => "Grupo que recibira los correos de validación como Administración",
             'required' => false,
             "mapped" => false,
             'placeholder' => 'Elige el Grupo',
             'class'    => RoleGroup::class,
             'label_attr' => array(
                'class' => 'control-label'
                ),
             'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control select',
                )
        ))
```

Then in the controller I try to assign the value, but without success:

```
$form["roleGroup"]->setData(21);
```

I have also tried with:

```
$form->get("roleGroup")->setData(21);

return $this->render('configuration/index.html.twig', 
    [
        'id'      => $id,    
        'title'   => "General",
        'partial' => "general.html.twig",
        'form'    => $form->createView(),
    ]);
```

Can someone tell me what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not the same since he's trying to access it and I'm trying to assign the value. And I saw that before and it didn't help me.

Comment: are sure, than i'm removes flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your form field is type of `EntityType::class`, expected data should be an object of type `RoleGroup::class` while you're trying to pass an integer value.

Therefore you need to fetch your entity and pass it as field data. Supposing that `21` is the `id` of your entity, it should be something like this in your Controller

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$entity = $em->getRepository(RoleGroup::class)->findOneBy(['id' => 21]);
$form->get('roleGroup')->setData($entity);
```

Alternatively you can also set `data` directly on your form field as default value

```
->add('roleGroup', EntityType::class, array(
         ...
         'data' => $entity
     ));
```

Comment: Exactly that was my problem which I didn't see, thank you very much.